# Static route from 192.168.98.192 to 192.168.72.201

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, routing

I'm new to this so it might be an obvious question.

I've given two servers on the same network, one with ip **192.168.72.201** and another one **192.168.98.192**.

They can't communicate with each other because *"no layer-2 traffic is forwarded between switch ports and direct communication between servers, even when on the same subnet, is not possible in our network"*.

In order to talk to each other I need to add a static route.

I've spent a whole day trying to add things into `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` but it still can't communicate because all the examples I could find were having only last number in IP address different...

-- Server 1 stats --

```
~# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4161<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500<br/>
        inet 192.168.98.192  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0

~# ip route
default via 192.168.64.1 dev eth0 proto static onlink
```

-- Server 2 stats --

```
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.72.201(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.192.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.64.1
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, adding

```
routes:
    - to: 192.168.72.201
      via: 192.168.64.1
```

to netplan file worked.